# Layer attribution does not appear

Tags: openlayers-3

I don't understand why the "attribution" does not appear with the layer.

Have you an idea ?

```
   var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'OSM',
        type: 'base',
        minResolution : 2,
        attributions: [new ol.Attribution({
        html: "© OpenStreetMap -Mitwirkende, SRTM | Affichage de la carte: © OpenTopoMap (CC-BY-SA)"
        })],
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: '//{a-c}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attributions` is [a property of the `source` property of a layer](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/apidoc/ol.Attribution.html).

So that means your layer definition should look like this:

```
var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  title: 'OSM',
  type: 'base',
  minResolution : 2,
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: '//{a-c}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    attributions: [new ol.Attribution({
      html: "© OpenStreetMap -Mitwirkende, SRTM | Affichage de la carte: © OpenTopoMap (CC-BY-SA)"
    })],
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Good to hear it worked out. Please consider [accepting my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), as this is an indication for other StackOverflow users that my answer is a possible solution.